# My suggested edit was rejected

Tags: discussion

For some reason my [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6374941) was rejected. One of the rejector's reason says:

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits
>   that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of
>   the post's owner.

This is **clearly** not true. From the post title it says `libstdc++` and the question was retagged to `libstdc++` because the STL **is not** the `libstdc++`. The question also uses code from `libstdc++` and is about `libstdc++` and not code from `STL`. My edit changed the text from `STL` to `libstdc++` since the original editor forgot to do so. In my edit reason, I said:

> Last editor forgot to change text inside the question as well

Two people approved my edit, so obviously I was doing something right. How do I get my edit approved?

BTW here is what the question originally said:

> i am reading the stl code for enable_shared_from_this, it is in the
>   gcc-4.9.2\libstdc++-v3\include\bits\shared_ptr.h.

Already he is contradicting himself. Yet the rejector says:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read,
>   easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either
>   completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

It obviously makes it **more accurate**.

The original editor's message said:

> this has absolutely nothing to do with the STL

Comment: There's quite a lot of stuff that needs fixing in that post, changing just that wasn't enough. Also you can't assume people reviewing the post know what STL or libstdc++ are, your summary could have been clearer (the "last editor" or edit message isn't directly visible in the review screen)

Comment: The removal of the *stl* tag does not indicate a that *stl* does not necessarily belong in problem statement, from the reviewer's perspective. I can write a post saying I am using *eclipse* as my Java IDE and my code kept getting a null pointer exception, but tagging it *eclipse* would be an inappropriate use of the tag.

Comment: @Compass Not really. The question asker says "he is already contradicting himself", which is correct. Saying "code from the stl" then proceeding to quote code from libstdc++ is contradictory.

Comment: @remyabel I'm speaking from the view of someone who doesn't know C++ while viewing such a suggested edit. I would have skipped, but I'm sure at least one of those reviewers wouldn't know the difference between *stl* and *libstdc++* and still partook in voting.

Comment: @Compass And how would somebody unfamiliar with Java or Eclipse know that the question shouldn't contain an Eclipse tag?

Comment: @remyabel I can only explain examples in languages I can understand! x_x I guess a better example would be... gah I can't think of a language-neutral example.

Comment: @Compass But then that would require somebody to be familiar with [tag:language-agnostic] questions ;)